# Como recorrer todos los checkbox que tienen una clase y obtener su value con jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, formularios

Tengo un grupo de input checkbox que tinen cierta class que quisiera recorrer e ir comparando
el value que contiene.
lo que he intentado fue de esta manera:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-item" value="715">

$('input[type=checkbox].checkbox-item').each(function () {

     let value = $(this).val()
     console.log(value)
 });
```

de esta forma no selecciona nada solo he podido seleccionar todos los inputs pero aparecen todos los checkbox con otras clases

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
```

como podria recorrer todos los input checkbox que tengan class="checkbox-item" y obtener el valor que tiene en value=""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que acceder al `input:checkbox` y dentro buscar la clase que quieres.

Otra cosa, es que puedes obtener solo los checkbox marcados, asi que te dejo todos, y solo los marcados.

```js
//Todos los valores
$("input:checkbox[class=checkbox-item]").each(function(){
    let value = $(this).val()
    console.log(value)
});
console.log("----");
//Solo los checked
$("input:checkbox[class=checkbox-item]:checked").each(function(){
    let value = $(this).val()
    console.log(value)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-item" value="4" checked/> 4 <br>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-item" value="3"/> 3 <br>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-item" value="1" checked /> 1 <br>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-item" value="1"/> 2 <br>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-item" value="5" checked/> 5 <br>
```

Comment: Gracias!!! funciona perfecto @Excorpion